# How to save Flask-SocketIO messages with Flask-SQLAlchemy and Javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

I have followed this tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQDzNNt6xd4 for creating a chat application. I tried to save the messages but it does not work. 
I also followed this tutorial for saving the chat history: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pigpDSOBNMc

**Here is the Javascript code:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    console.log('I am connected');

    //This sends the message I am now connected
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.send("I am connected");
    });

    socket.on('message', data => {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        p.innerHTML = data;
        document.querySelector('#display-message-section').append(p);
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('some-event', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    //Sending message to recipient
    document.querySelector('#send_message').onclick = () => {
        socket.send(document.querySelector('#user_message').value);
    }

});
```

**Here is the application file:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'm\x13\x96\xe2\xce/\xc8\x1b\xc4\x93@\xf4%\x19\x12\xca]\x9b\xc8\xe3;\xd5\x96='
socketio = SocketIO(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class History(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    message = db.Column('message', db.String(500))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<History %r>' % self.message

@socketio.on('message')
def message(p):
    print('Messages: ' + p)
    message = History(message=p)
    db.session.add(message)
    db.session.commit()
    send(p, broadcast=True)


@app.route("/")
def chat():
    messages = History.query.all()
    return render_template('chat.html', messages=messages)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

**Here is the HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <nav>
    </nav>

    <div id="main-section">
      <!-- Room selection -->
      <nav id="sidebar">
      </nav>
      <!-- Message area -->
      <div id="rightside-pannel">
        <!-- Display message -->
        <div id="display-message-section">  
        </div>

        <form method="POST" action="/">
        <div id="input-area">

          <input type="text" id="user_message" placeholder="Type here..."
          autocomplete="off">
          <button type="button" id="send_message">Send</button>
         </form>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Get username -->
    <!-- SocketIO JS -->
  </body>
    <!-- Custom SocketIO KS -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/socketio.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: "It does not work" is too vague. Can you explain exactly what you expected and what happened instead?

Comment: Hi
It does not save the messages and does not display it on the page. Every time I refresh the page it disappears. I want to keep the messages. Thanks.

Comment: You need to debug this from the beginning. Add print statements in the JS connect handler to make sure that handler runs. Then keep following the data and add more prints in the server before and after saving to database. If the messages aren't being saved, you will find that some of those prints do not execute. That should give you more clues about the problem.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try it out.

Comment: I'm getting this message from console on FireFox: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=8a388dd5655449e2b47b20a45ccc003d. How to resolve this?

Comment: That could happen for many reasons, impossible for me to tell. You need to now look at the server to see if there are any problems on that side. But note that this is the websocket connection, the server should still work in polling mode when websocket cannot be connected.

Comment: Everything in JS file seems to work. I added print statements as you said, but I still facing the problem. Is there a way to do it differently ? For example to retrieve the data from input and then save it? I just don't know how. Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown the complete code, so I can't really tell you what's wrong. I assume the message that you want to save is this `I am connected` that you issue from the connect handler in JS? Does a `console.log()` in that function appear in your console? Does the server receive that message?

Comment: Hi Miguel. Here is the complete code. You can now take a look :) Thanks!